# put lines of a d3 force graph in the foreground

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I cannot find a way to put the lines of a d3js force-directed graph to the foreground. I want that my divs(the nodes of the graph) are behind the lines. I can change the opacity of the divs but that's not what i want and I can change the divs z-index to negative but that makes them unaccessible for dragging...

anyone knows a solution?

I got a fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/5jgrf5h8/

```
//create a svg in the body of index.html
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .classed("simulation", 1)
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

//setting the links

var glink = svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "links")
.selectAll("links")
.data(links).enter();

var link = glink.append("polyline")
.attr("stroke-width", 2);



//setting the nodes. they will be div elements
var node = d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "nodes")
  .selectAll(".node")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("div")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("id", function(d){return d.id;})
  .style("background", function(d) { return color(d.group); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution comes to mine based on two premises:

1. Positioned elements appear in front of un-positioned elements.
2. Draw order affects layering

So, two quick changes should fix this. In your css:

```
svg { position: absolute; }
```

And then just append the `.node` divs before the svg.

[Updated fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/hr3g86w9/)

If you need to drag the boxes, you can also set pointer events to none for the svg - [different updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bve7j5fv/).